# Упорядочивание (не сортировка!) массива по индексу

Tags: массивы, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как упорядочить массив по индексу следующим образом:
Из:

```
[0] => длодлодо ...
[1] => фываыва.
[4] => sdfsadfsa.
[6] => Оsdfgdfg ....
[7] => sdfgdfg- ...
[9] => вапвап
```

в:

```
[0] => длодлодо ...
[1] => фываыва.
[2] => sdfsadfsa.
[3] => Оsdfgdfg ....
[4] => sdfgdfg- ...
[5] => вапвап
```

В мануале подходящего ничего не нашел. Надеюсь, что упустил нужную функцию и вы мне её подскажите. А то придется изобретать велик. Спасибо.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$new_arr = array_values($old_arr);
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/HQPiG0)