# Отсортировать массив PHP

Tags: массивы, php

Привет, есть массив:

```
$uri = array(

   0   => 'catalog',
   10  => 'mushrooms',
   17  => 'snow',
   165 => 'id1777'

);
```

как привести его к такому виду:

```
$uri = array(

   0  => 'catalog',
   1  => 'mushrooms',
   2  => 'snow',
   3  => 'id1777'

);
```

главное чтобы не потерялся порядок значений, а ключи стали по-порядку (0,1,2,3... и тд)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отвечал уже чуть ранее на подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/256440/php-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83):

```
$newUri = array_values($uri);
```

Comment: Прошу прощения я нашёл такую штуку:

    array_splice($uri, 0, 0);

работает вроде аналогично, можете что нибудь прокомментировать?

Comment: В PHP есть много вещей которые можно сделать разными способами, разница в том, какую смысловую нагрузку будут нести эти конструкции для программистов, которые будут смотреть ваш код позднее. Если я вижу array_splice($arr, 0, 0) -  я сразу начну думать, что тут обрезается массив, но странные параметры передаются (0,0), придется искать в документации что они делают, это лишнее время. А при конструкции array_values - я понимаю что берутся значения массива и точка.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
$uri = array(

   0   => 'catalog',
   10  => 'mushrooms',
   17  => 'snow',
   165 => 'id1777'

);

$newUri = array();

foreach($uri as $v) {
    $newUri[] = $v;
}
```

Comment: дело в том что хочу как раз отойти от foreach полностью

Comment: От foreach отходить не надо, его надо использовать правильно и в нужных местах. Вероятно у вас проблема с поисковыми запросами, по запросу "[get value array php][1]", мне сразу предложили функцию `array_values`. Как показывает практика, около 80% новичковых велосипедов уже решены разработчиками PHP. 

[1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=get+value+array+php

Comment: А вообще - думаю стоит [прочитать][1] что делают функции для работы с массивами, их много, они многое умеют, бегло ознакомиться с общим списком и детально посмотреть примеры заинтересовавших вас функций. В следующий раз вы будите приблизительно знать где искать решение поставленной задачи.

[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php

Comment: Спасибо вам за информацию, очень полезная ссылка и раскрытый ответ!